# How to solve $ \frac{\left( \sqrt{2} \right) ^a}{a}=1$

Tags: calculus

I know that $2$ and $4$ solve this problem. I also assume that there real solutions. 
However I don't know how to bring $$ \frac{\left( \sqrt{2} \right) ^a}{a}=1$$ into a form so that the solutions, at least integer solutions are trivial.

Comment: You should study the variations of the function $\sqrt{2}^a-a$

Comment: Hint: plot the graph of y=a and $y=2^{a/2}$

Comment: Not possible to come up with a closed expression in elementary functions, but might be possible using the [Lambert W-function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The function $x\mapsto \frac{\sqrt{2}^x}{x}$ is *convex* on $(0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

Consider 
\begin{align}
\frac{2^{a/2}}{a} = 1
\end{align}
for which
\begin{align}
2^{a/2} = a.
\end{align}
Now taking the logarithm of both sides leads to
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{2} = \frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(2)}.
\end{align}
This shows that $a$ is of the form $2^{m}$ since $\ln(2^{m}) = m \ln(2)$. With this in mind it is seen that
\begin{align}
2^{m-1} = m.
\end{align}
There are only two values for $m$. Those are $m \in \{1, 2\}$. Thus the values of $a$ are $a \in \{ 2, 4\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1**:  Graph the functions $y=2^{x/2}$ and $y=x$.

**Hint 2**:  Differentiate the function $f(x)=2^{x/2}-x$.

Comment: Oh, I see these hints were made in comments beneath the OP.  Great minds and all that....